# How to make the text scrollable with canvas.NewText() with fyne Go

Tags: go, fyne

I am new to programming and i want to develop a application but i need show to users very large text in my application.
I am not sure widget.NewRichTextWithText() is for this purpose.
This code working as i expected.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    
    w := a.NewWindow("Some Practice")
    
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(400, 400))
    
    text := widget.NewRichTextWithText((strings.Repeat("this\n", 100)))
    
    c := container.NewMax(container.NewVScroll(text))
    
    w.SetContent(c)
    
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

But this one does not work.

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "strings"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    
    w := a.NewWindow("Some Practice")
    
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(400, 400))
    
    text := canvas.NewText(strings.Repeat("this\n", 100), color.White)
    
    c := container.NewMax(container.NewVScroll(text))
    
    w.SetContent(c)
    
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Becuase the " \n " showing as invalid character instead of new line when i run the application.
My aim is showing very large text "top to bottom scrollable" with canvas.NewText() but " \n " character does not work. Instead of top to bottom scrollable showing text it is printing this as this?this?this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`widget.Label`](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget#Label) to display "simple" texts:

```
text := widget.NewLabel(strings.Repeat("this\n", 100))
```

Note that `widget.Label` can be "styled" (e.g. you can make it *italic* or **bold**).

[`widget.RichText`](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget#RichText) should be used if you want to display text that has parts (called segments) with different styles and formatting. `widget.Label` can only be styled as a whole.

Comment: should i use the widget.NewLabel() even i show a text to users that is about 200+ words ?

Comment: @BrokenArmor If you don't need to format different parts of the text differently, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas.Text` does not do smart text parsing, so you would have to do that yourself.
In general the `widget` package has smart widgets that do this all for you, and the `canvas` package is for lower level drawing normally used to build other widgets.

Comment: Can you give an example from one of those smart widgets ? because i am new to programming and when i go to documentation of fyne packages my mind easily confusing.

Comment: All widgets are built from canvas elements. You can check the source code of anything in the `widget` package, for example. https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/tree/master/widget